# Retrieve json key on searching child value

Tags: json, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have this json object

```
{
    '2807281f81481ffbd4183da0003dfe1820343ff6': {
    'macaddr': '64:a3:cb:ba:5c:76',
    'parameters': [
      '1',
      '121',
      '3',
      '6',
      '15',
      '119',
      '252'
    ],
    'ip': '192.168.1.120',
    'vendor_id': 'MSFT 5.0',
    'HOSTID': '2807281f81481ffbd4183da0003dfe1820343ff6',
    'time': 1479309949.7988095,
    'os': 'Apple iPhone',
    'hostname': 'Alles-iPhone'
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to to retrieve the key on searching for the specific ip. Then use the key to retrieve matching values from another dictionary.

> EDIT 1:
>   Answered myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up using the list comprehension and iteritems. global_hostlist is the required dictionary and  hostlist is the dict to match.

```
if ip in [host_ip[1]["ip"] for host_ip in self.global_hostlist.iteritems()]:
    key = [host_ip[1]["HOSTID"] for host_ip in self.global_hostlist.iteritems() if host_ip[1]["ip"] == ip]
    if key[0]:
        self.hostlist[key[0]] = self.global_hostlist[key[0]]
```

Comment: If you think the resolution you found would be helpful to other users, feel free to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question. Otherwise, you can [delete your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Comment: I am a novice user to SO, and realized just now. Hope it helps someone. I self answered it. Thanks